# printing content of text file on console c++

Tags: c++, fstream, file-handling

I am trying to print the contents of a file to the console, but it is displaying the address instead. Please help me out (also, please suggest another way than `std::cout`, as we haven't studied that in class, and I do not understand it but I'm supposed to use that, I guess).

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream f("board.txt");
    if(f.is_open())
    {
        cout<<f;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"ERROR:no file opened.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `cout<<f;` compiles only because there is a standard `operator<<` that takes a `void*` as input, and prior to C++11 `std::ifstream` had a [`void*` conversion operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). But in C++11 and later, this code should not compile anymore.

Comment: If this is for a class assignment, then what the teacher probably want is the simple naive solution which the teacher probably taught you (and is included in just about any decent book): Use a loop to read input and write output piece by piece.

Comment: its a  project. its just that my teacher never used that std even though we do use some functions and user defined functions . i just dont know I should use it or not

Comment: You should write a OS script to do this.  The OS is optimized for this kind of stuff.  In Windows Command you could write: `more filename.txt`.  In Linux, you could try `less filename.txt".

Answer (score 6):

There's no standard overload of `operator<<` which takes a stream directly to output the contents of that stream.

The naive solution to output a whole file is to read the contents of the input stream in a loop, and output it, piece by piece-

But there is one [`operator<<` overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) which takes a [stream *buffer*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_streambuf), which you can get through the [`rdbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf) function:

```
std::cout << f.rdbuf();
```

This should write *all* the contents of the file.

Comment: This approach is plenty fast!  If you need faster performance than this, you'll probably need to use OS calls and platform specific code.

Comment: Careful handing something like this in. If the instructor is expecting the typical "get input put input" loop of the naïve solution and you give them the "professional" optimal solution things can get weird.